# Java override class member with different type

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have the following enums:

```
public enum CarManufacturer {
    VOLKSWAGEN, CHEVROLET, DODGE, ...
}
public enum PlaneManufacturer {
    LOCKHEED, AIRBUS, BOEING, ...
}
```

and the following superclass:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int size;
    int weight;
    ...
}
```

What i want to do is have an explicit manufacturer inside vehicle so everyone that receives a Vehicle class knows it has a manufacturer.

Ex:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int size;
    int weight;
    int manufacturer;

    abstract int getManufacturer () {};
}

public class Plane extends Vehicle {
    PlaneManufacturer manufacturer;
    PlaneManufacturer getManufacturer () { return this.manufacturer; }
    ...
}
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    CarManufacturer manufacturer;
    CarManufacturer getManufacturer () { return this.manufacturer; }
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Manufacturer` interface, and have your enums implement that interface.

```
public interface Manufacturer {}

public enum CarManufacturer implements Manufacturer {
    VOLKSWAGEN, CHEVROLET, DODGE, ...
}
public enum PlaneManufacturer implements Manufacturer {
    LOCKHEED, AIRBUS, BOEING, ...
}
```

Then in your `Vehicle` class, you can:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int size;
    int weight;
    Manufacturer manufacturer;

    Manufacturer getManufacturer () {
        return manufacturer;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every enum extends from Enum abstract superclass implicitly. So, you can reference the attribute as Enum at Vehicle superclass, as in:

```
    public class Vehicle {
        int size;
        int weight;
        Enum manufacturer;

        abstract Enum getManufacturer () {};
    }
```

Comment: But this doesn't stop someone using their enum `Fruit` where a `Manufacturer` should be.

Comment: And you would expect to have a method like `manufacture` on the returned object, which Enum does not have.